# hdparm: Are parameters (like spindown time set using -S) saved on machine or on the hard disk?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, hdparm

Say, I connect my external hard drive to a machine/computer and set the spindown time to 5 seconds using:

```
hdparm -S1 <disk dir>
```

I test this setup, and the disk does spin down after it is unmounted, and spins up when it is mounted. Say that, then, I disconnect this drive from my machine, disconnect power from the disks, and then connect them to some other machine. While the disks still have the same behavior, that is, will it spin down 5 seconds after unmounted/unused? Basically, is the changed parameter value for "spindown time" saved on the machine or on the disk, so that the behavior remains the same even if the disks are disconnected or powered off.

For context, let me describe what I am trying to do. I have a few external hard drives that I am setting up for a remote application. I want them to spindown when they are unmounted, so that I can save on power or heat, such that only one is mounted and drawing power. I want to initialize the setup on all the drives once and then be done with this, so that I can install them at the remote location easily and they still work in case the computer there is power-cycled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That command writes to the hard disk itself, not the computer.